# Условие времени в JavaScript

Tags: jquery, setinterval, изображения, javascript, if

На странице загружается большая картинка таким образом:

```
$(function() {
    $('#urlimage').hide();
    $('#urlimage').load( function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('#urlimage').show();
    } );
});
```

**Работа:** показываем текст: **"Loading.."** - и как только загрузилась картинка, спрячем **"Loading.."**, и показываем картинку.

Все работает по идеи, осталось дать условие скрипту, например если картинка не загрузилась меньше минуты, то прекращаем загрузку, и показываем текст: "Похоже появились ошибки во время загрузки картинки, обновите страницу"
Как решить задачу? Спасибо, за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
$(function() {
    $('#urlimage').hide();
    var imgLoaded = false;
    var error = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!imgLoaded) {
            $('#loader').html('error');
            error = true;
        }
    }, 1000 * 60);
    $('#urlimage').load( function() {
        if (!error) {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#urlimage').show();
            imgLoaded = true;
        }
    } );
});
```

Проверку `if (!error)` добавил на случай, если изображение таки загрузится после отображения сообщения об ошибке ибо функцию `load()`, в отличие от `ajax()`, отменить нельзя.

Comment: Отличная реализация, благодарю!

Comment: complete проверять надо.